i was using bert model 'A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an a dtype
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'keras_layer_4' (type KerasLayer).
A KerasTensor is symbolic: it's a placeholder for a shape an a dtype. It doesn't have any actual numerical value. You cannot convert it to a NumPy array.
Call arguments received by layer 'keras_layer_4' (type KerasLayer):
• inputs=
• training=None
i tried chat gpt and copilot but can't solve the error
